# Azure MySql server out of memory issues

Tags: mysql, azure

**Background:**

I have an Azure database for MySql single server instance. The database has 12 very small tables (<= 10 rows per table). These tables are queried (only) by automatic tests in a C# application that are run ~20000 times daily. The tests run very simple queries, a few of them also create a temporary table and then immidiately delete it.
The server is **Basic, 2 vCore(s), 50 GB** and has MySql version 8.0.

**The problem**:

Recently we’ve been seeing many test failures with the following error messages:

1. Out of memory; check if mysqld or some other process uses all available memory; if not, you may have to use 'ulimit' to allow mysqld to use more memory or you can add more swap space
2. An error occurred when accessing your server. Please retry or report your issues.
3. Failed to read the result set ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer

Looking at the memory usage over the past 7 days it seems there's no problem with an average usage of ~26% and a maximum of just over 30%:
[image]

I read the Azure documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-troubleshoot-low-memory-issues) to troubleshoot memory issues, but nothing seems relevant for my scenario. As stated, the database is very small, as are the tables  and only simple queries are run against it. I would like to try to understand what is going on before increasing RAM / scaling up.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Database for MySQL flexible server, Overview - Monitoring, Cpu and Memory, for my server, suddenly dropped from 95-96% memory usage (out of 2 GiB RAM total) to zero % memory usage - I guess it's a bug in Azure monitoring.

Anyway, you can query your Azure MySql server directly for memory usage, from the Cloud Shell:

mysql -h YOUR-DATABASE.mysql.database.azure.com -u YOUR-DB-USER-NAME -p "--ssl-ca=DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem" -e "SELECT * FROM sys.memory_global_by_current_bytes WHERE event_name LIKE 'memory/innodb/buf_buf_pool'\G"

You will get smth like:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       event_name: memory/innodb/buf_buf_pool
    current_count: 4
    current_alloc: 523.52 MiB
current_avg_alloc: 130.88 MiB
       high_count: 4
       high_alloc: 523.52 MiB
   high_avg_alloc: 130.88 MiB
```

Comment: What is your Azure instance type?

Comment: Azure Database for MySQL flexible server. Burstable, B1ms, 1 vCores, 2 GiB RAM, 20 GiB storage. MySQL version
8.0. Azure Metrics - Host Memory Percent, Avg - dropped to exactly zero on Sept 29. Still MySQL is working OK per se, except that auto backups are not created anymore. Restarting didn't help.

Comment: Pavel, Consider opening your own Question for assistance.  Have you completed Gracefule shutdown of OS and restart of OS and MySQL to get back to normal? When you open you own question, please post the new Question number here so we can find your current status.  Thank you.

Comment: Can't shutdown an OS via Azure Database for MySQL service, only to restart the service. Didn't submit the Azure ticket, cause Azure wants $$ for support (and I have doubts about its support efficiency). Instead I made a local DB backup via DBeaver (non-snap install on Ubuntu), and dumped the DB locally, so I can restore my DB even if Azure DB screws up altogether.

Comment: View our profile, please.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are getting out of memory error messages in your Azure MYSQL single server.
First thing, I would say here is to try migrating from Azure MYSQL Single to flexible server which is best for production workloads that require zone resiliency, predictable performance, maximum control with IOPs scaling, custom maintenance window and cost optimization controls.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/whats-happening-to-mysql-single-server.
To troubleshoot this issue,please try to monitor the memory usage specifically during the test runs when the failures occur. This will give you a better understanding of how memory is being utilized during the critical periods. You can use Azure portal metrics or monitoring tools to gather this information.
If the memory issues error still persists, I would suggest trying to increase to a higher tier plan.

Additionally, Monitoring data about your servers helps you troubleshoot and optimize your workload. Azure Database for MySQL provides various metrics that give insight into the behavior of your server.
Metrics
All Azure metrics have a one-minute frequency, and each metric provides 30 days of history. You can configure alerts on the metrics. For step by step guidance, see [How to set up alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/how-to-alert-on-metric). Other tasks include setting up automated actions, performing advanced analytics, and archiving history. For more information, see the [Azure Metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/data-platform) Overview.

**List of metrics**
These metrics are available for Azure Database for MySQL:
From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-monitoring

Potentially increase vcore
Permanently  increase resources(memory tier vcore etc , ) and pay more in the long run.
Queries main cause of memory usage: Use Microsoft Intelligent Performance tools to explore queries that are considered top consumers and also learn about missing indexes along with recommendation and full analysis for your workload. [Query store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-query-store)